# Edittext input type DD/MMM/YYYY

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

Is there any way to have an input type of `Edittext` which accepts a date with format DD/MMM/YYYY?

I have already tried setting inputtype="date". But it accepts date in format of DD/MM/YYYY.

Does google provide customization for google keyboard?

Comment: use date picker widget  rather than entering date directly in edittext. You can get the selected date by user and format date in required format and display it.

Comment: Try this:-  [Android Date Time Picker](http://www.journaldev.com/9976/android-date-time-picker-dialog)

Comment: I have it already but it's project requirement that user can input the date also